# How to sum the value of two columns from two different tables using Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, eloquent

I am using the jQuery datatables plugin and adding the column valores_receber (values_to_receive) using a foreach loop that do the sum but in a separate way as you can see in the following code.

```
public function anyDataReceber() {

$clientes = Partner::whereHas('faturamentos', function($q){
        $q->where('status', '<>', 'CANCELADO');
    })
    ->orWhereHas('faturamentosLivres', function ($q) {
        $q->where('status','<>','CANCELADO');
    })
    ->with('faturamentos')
    ->with('faturamentosLivres');

return Datatables::of($clientes)
    ->addColumn('valores_receber', function ($clientes) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($clientes->faturamentos as $fatura1) {
            if ($fatura1->status != 'CANCELADO') $total += $fatura1->total_usd - $fatura1->valor_pago;
        }
        foreach($clientes->faturamentosLivres as $fatura2) {
            if ($fatura2->status != 'CANCELADO') $total += $fatura2->total_usd - $fatura2->valor_pago;
        }
        return number_format($total,2,',','.');
    })
    ->addColumn('action', function ($clientes) {
        $actions = '';
        $actions = '<a href="/admin/financeiro-matriz/contas-receber/'.$clientes->id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Visualizar</a>';
        return $actions;
    })
    ->make(true);
```

}

The problem here is that the datatable can not order the column valores_receber because this very column does not exist in the result query from Eloquent.

I researched about the SUM() function from mySQL but I can't make a solution using Eloquent and the tables relationships.

I checked the following answers that should be in the right track but are using normal SQL instead and from what I researched it needs some sort of join or union statements, but how to perform that in Eloquent?

- [How to calculate sum of two columns from two different tables without where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246818/how-to-calculate-sum-of-two-columns-from-two-different-tables-without-where-clau)
- [How to sum data of two different columns of two different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206763/how-to-sum-data-of-two-different-columns-of-two-different-tables)

So for the datatable to be able to order the column valores_receber, I need that column to show up in the results of some sort of Eloquent statement.

What I am trying to achieve is:

- make the query using Eloquent that sums the values of the columns total_usd that is present in both tables faturamentos and faturamentos_livres (invoices and free_invoices)
- those tables need to be restricted by the status column that must be any value but CANCELADO (Canceled). This status column is an ENUM type

**EDIT:** I am using DB:raw() as suggested by @d1c1pl3 but I still want to know an elegant solution using Eloquent. What follows is my ugly attempt, that works, using raw queries and it is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7432219/2465086

```
public function anyDataReceber() {

// 1 - getting all IDs of clients that have faturamentos or faturamentosLivres

    $clientes = Partner::whereHas('faturamentos', function($q){
            $q->where('status', '<>', 'CANCELADO');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('faturamentosLivres', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status','<>','CANCELADO');
        })
        ->with('faturamentos')
        ->with('faturamentosLivres')
        ->pluck('id')
        ->toArray();

// 2 - Converting to string for use in the query

    $ids = implode(',',$clientes);

// 3 - the ugly query that I want to do using Eloquent. It filters by the status and filters by clients´ ids returned before. It is not appealing either because it uses subselects and a join

    $result = DB::select(DB::raw(
                 'SELECT partners.client, cliente_id, (SUM(t.total_usd) - SUM(t.valor_pago)) AS valores_receber
FROM (SELECT cliente_id, total_usd, valor_pago FROM faturamentos WHERE status <> "CANCELADO" AND cliente_id IN ('.$ids.')
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cliente_id, total_usd, valor_pago FROM faturamentos_livres WHERE status <> "CANCELADO" AND cliente_id IN ('.$ids.')) t
JOIN partners ON partners.id= cliente_id 
GROUP BY cliente_id'
                 ));

// 4 - converting to Collection because the Datatables class expects it

    $result = collect($result);

// 5 - The return is the only part that is easy to read and feels like it is in the right track

    return Datatables::of($result)
        ->editColumn('valores_receber', function ($result) {
            return number_format($result->valores_receber,2,',','.');
        })
        ->addColumn('action', function ($result) {
            $actions = '';
            $actions = '<a href="/admin/financeiro-matriz/contas-receber/'.$result->cliente_id.'" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Visualizar</a>';
            return $actions;
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it with mysql I would use the raw expressions

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: it seems there is no way to do it with Eloquent alone then. I will try to use the raw expression and share the results